# For a commutative ring $A$, $S$ multiplicative subset, if $p \in A$ is prime, then $p/s$ is prime in $S^{-1}A$.

Tags: ring-theory

For a commutative ring $A$, $S$ multiplicative subset, if $p \in A$ is prime with $(p) \cap S = \emptyset$, then $p/s$ is prime in $S^{-1}A$.

How do I prove this? Any suggestion or hint?

Comment: Note that this is true only if $p \notin S$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $(p/s)|ab$, for $a,b\in S^{-1}A$.  Then prove that $(p/s)|a$ or $(p/s)|b$, using the structure of $a,b$ as elements of $S^{-1}A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 
$$
\frac{p}{s} \mid \frac{a}{c}\frac{b}{d}
$$
Then, $\exists m/n \in S^{-1}A$ such that
$$
\frac{mp}{sn} = \frac{ab}{cd}
$$
So
$$
mpcd = absn \text{ in } A
$$
Does this help?